# Pandas - trimming whitespace, error with number of columns

Tags: python, csv, pandas, whitespace

I am attempting to parse a large pipe-delimited text file to remove whitespace. The text file is exported from a database as 125GB file, but removing whitespaces would bring it down to a more manageable size.

```
 for chunk in      pd.read_table(path,sep='|',skipinitialspace=True,chunksize=ch):
chunk.to_csv(outfile,sep='|',index=False,chunksize=ch,mode='a')
```

However I run into the below error about the number of columns

CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 40 fields in line 431774, saw 59

I checked line 431774 and it does map to 40 fields. As far as I can tell, the full file is organised at 40 fields per line.

Any ideas why this could be happening?

Comment: It's hard to tell without looking at the actual file, but try set `error_bad_lines=False` in the read_table function to ignore the lines with the problem. You can then see how big the resulting file is, and decide if trying to remove the white spaces is actually worth it.

Comment: what is your goal - just to get rid of whitespaces? How do you want to use cleaned data? would it make sense to read your data directly from DB and save it to more appropriate data format like HDF5, etc.?

Comment: yes, my goal is to just get rid of whitespaces. I'm doing this as a once-off to extract a table from a DB and transfer to separate environment (a contrived task for annoying business reasons...). As the table is large ~60M rows, I've had to extract the table as fixed-length text fields. Trimming the whitespace then reduces the file to a manageable size. 

i went with error_bad_lines=False as a very small number of rows were dropped. However still an interesting issue, given I could not find any evidence of the additional columns